# Using ffmpeg on MOV files created by iMovie

Tags: imovie, video

It looks like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) will not work with MOV files created using iMovie. Is there a way to batch convert these files (which are HUGE) to a compressed format, preferably mp4? I've also tried [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) with no success (though I assume ffmpeg is under the hood).

Comment: Why would ffmpeg not work? I've used it hundreds of times to convert .mov(s) to .mp4(s). It would help to know how exactly you are 'trying' to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [MPEG StreamClip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html) also. There is Batch mode — <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

But it's hard to tell based on your information why Handbrake was not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Video Monkey](http://videomonkey.org) (although it uses ffmpeg under the hood), but if HandBrake doesn't work for you, I doubt it will as well.